# Ld.so.1: java: fatal: relocation error: file : symbol PQconnectdb: referenced symbol not found

Tags: java, linux, postgresql, библиотеки

Я написал следующую `java` программу

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.*;

public class Sample {
        public native long Traveser(String Path);

        public native void Configure(String Path);
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException  {
            long count=0;       
            int CountComputers;
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(
                    "/export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/countcomputers.txt");
            DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(fstream);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
            String result=br.readLine();
            CountComputers=Integer.parseInt(result);
            input.close();
            fstream.close();
            Connection con = null;
            Statement st = null;
                ResultSet rs = null;    
               String url = "jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.8:5432/NexentaSearch";
                String user = "postgres";
                String password = "valter89";
            ArrayList<String> paths = new ArrayList<String>();
            try
            {
                con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
                        st = con.createStatement();
                        rs = st.executeQuery("select path from tasks order by id");
                while (rs.next()) { paths.add(rs.getString(1)); };
                PrintWriter zzz = null;
                    try
                    {
                            zzz = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("/export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/readwaysfromdatabase.txt"));
                    }
                    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
                    {
                            System.out.println("Error");
                            System.exit(0);
                    }
                    for (int i=0; i<paths.size(); i++)
                {
                    zzz.println("paths[i]=" + paths.get(i) + "\n");
                    }
                    zzz.close();

            }
            catch (SQLException e) 
            {
                System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                    Sample inst=new Sample();
                for (int i=0; i<paths.size(); i++)
                {
                    inst.Configure("/etc/nsindexer.conf");
                    count = inst.Traveser(paths.get(i));
                    }
        }
        static {
            System.loadLibrary("nativetestlib");
        }
}
```

Откомпилировал ее и создал `jar` файл

```
./javac -classpath /folder/postgresql-8.4-703.jdbc3.jar -d /Samplejavaprogram/classes /Samplejavaprogram/src/Sample.java
./jar -cvf /Samplejavaprogram/Sample.jar /folder/postgresql-8.4-703.jdbc3.jar -C /Samplejavaprogram/classes/ .
```

Добавил в файл манифеста внутри `jar`-а следующие строки

```
Main-Class: Sample
Class-Path: /folder/postgresql-8.4-703.jdbc3.jar
```

Затем собрал библиотеку libnativetestlib.so c помощью команды

```
root@one: /usr/gcc/4.4/bin# ./gcc avl_tree.c buf_read.c db_prep.c file_process.c global_header.c traverser.c -o libnativetestlib.so -shared -fPIC -I/opt/jdk1.7.0_06/include -I/opt/jdk1.7.0_06/include/solaris -I/usr/gcc/4.4/bin/include -L/usr/gcc/4.4/bin/lib
```

При этом отмечу, что в папке `/usr/gcc/4.4/bin/lib` был файл `libpq.so`, который используется, так как в функциях `Traverser` и `Configure` происходит подключение `postgresql` базе данных. При попытке запуска созданной программы с помощью команды

```
./java -Djava.library.path=/opt/jdk1.7.0_06/lib -jar /Samplejavaprogram/Sample.jar
```

получил в результате сообщение

```
ld.so.1: java: fatal: relocation error: file /opt/jdk1.7.0_06/lib/libnativetestlib.so: symbol PQconnectdb: referenced symbol not found
```

В чем  причина ошибки и как ее исправить?

Answer (score 2):

Надо было добавить ключ `-lpq` при компиляции

```
root@one: /usr/gcc/4.4/bin# ./gcc avl_tree.c buf_read.c db_prep.c file_process.c global_header.c traverser.c -o libnativetestlib.so -shared -fPIC -I/opt/jdk1.7.0_06/include -I/opt/jdk1.7.0_06/include/solaris -I/usr/gcc/4.4/bin/include -L/usr/gcc/4.4/bin/lib -lpq
```